# Inserts from foreach statement inserts data vice versa

Tags: c#

In my `routePoints` list I got some values. They key is to insert them as they are in this list (in the same order). All SQL operations are combined into transactions. The method which I am interested in is `AddItems`.

When I debug `AddItems` - specifically the `foreach` loop inside - I see `routePoints` are ordered as expected and seems like it should insert in this order. Nevertheless at the end in the database, I see those values were inserted from bottom to top. Can anyone explains me why it happens?

**Example:** when it comes to `AddItems`, the `routePoints` contains `clientId` ordered as shown below (debugged):

```
6
5
4
```

But at the end when records are inserted there are in database as:

```
4
5
6
```

Full code:

```
public void UpdateOperation(Route route, IEnumerable<RouteClient> routePoints)
{
            Params = null;
            using var connection = Ctx.GetDbConn();
            var transactionScope = connection.BeginTransaction();
            string sql;

            try
            {
                Params = new List<IParam>
                    {
                        Ctx.addParam("@DriverId", route.DriverId, DbType.Int64),
                        Ctx.addParam("@RouteId", route.RouteId, DbType.Int64),
                        Ctx.addParam("@RouteDistance", route.RouteDistance, DbType.Decimal)
                    };
                sql = $"UPDATE {RouteTable} SET DriverId=@DriverId, RouteDistance=@RouteDistance " +
                      $"WHERE RouteId=@RouteId";
                Ctx.Update(sql, CommandType.Text, Params.ToArray(), transactionScope);

                RemoveItems(route.RouteId, transactionScope);
                AddItems(route.RouteId, routePoints, transactionScope);

                transactionScope.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transactionScope.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
}

public void AddItems(int routeId, IEnumerable<RouteClient> routePoints, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
{
     Params = null;

     foreach (var item in routePoints)
     {
         Params = new List<IParam>
         {
             Ctx.addParam("@RouteId", routeId, DbType.Int32),
             Ctx.addParam("@ClientId",  item.ClientId, DbType.Int32)
         };

          Ctx.Insert($"INSERT INTO {RouteClientsTable} (RouteId, ClientId) " +
          $"VALUES (@RouteId, @ClientId); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()",
          CommandType.Text, Params.ToArray(), transaction);
        }
}
```

Comment: Repeat over and over until it sinks in - SQL database tables are inherently *unordered*. If you want rows in a particular order, you need to request that order when `SELECT`-ing the rows.

Comment: How are you querying your database? Tables in a database implement *unordered* collections -- there is no "order" except the one you specify using `ORDER BY`. Any other order you get back is coincidental, regardless of the order rows were inserted in. (The `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` you've added appears to do nothing, given that there's no code to retrieve the result, but maybe there's something in `Ctx` we're not shown.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I just realased that foreach inserted rows correctly (6,5,4), nevertheless RouteClientId which is primary auto incremented field "ordered" rows in other order on table level. So when i saw foreeach's insert really added it ok as i saw it generate RouteClientId as 4129 (for 6), 4130 (for 5) and 4131 (for4) but tables ordered it as: 4131, 4130, 4131 . My question then is should i just (when getting records) to order by RouteClientId to get same as was inserted or i do really need some thing like additional column to keep thge order?

Comment: @JeroenMostert i mean like:  ORDER BY RouteClientId ASC; ... Hope you got my point

Comment: Since an `IDENTITY` increases, you can order by that on retrieval to get the same order as you had on insert (as long as the identity is not explicitly reset using `RESEED`). However, since an autoincrement ID is typically intended to be a "meaningless" surrogate key, it's not very good practice to rely on it if the rows have an intrinsic, meaningful order that should be preserved (for example, it could get lost if rows are migrated without `IDENTITY_INSERT`). For that something like an explicit `SEQUENCE` would be better.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you mean better to have like additional column to keep order by numbers would be better that not depending on pk? P.S If i would RESEED - would it also updated connected child tables keys?

Comment: `RESEED` has no effect on existing values, it only sets the value for new rows. In fact you can't change an identity value after inserting it at all, except by turning on `IDENTITY_INSERT`. Whether dependent tables get updated if you did that depends on whether the foreign key is defined with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`; that's independent of identity columns. Whether to rely on the identity being always increasing and reflecting the insert order, or using a separate column filled by a `SEQUENCE`, is mostly a matter of taste and what you think you can/should enforce in your DB.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i see. So can you confirm that adding e.g additional column to insert order values and then use it (order) to get in correct order would be fine that reling on pk? And second question does foreach always loops from as it was inserted (from top to bottom)?

Comment: `foreach` is guaranteed to use the order of the `IEnumerable` it operates on. This is always "from beginning to end". Of course, what's in that enumeration is up to you. Note that if other processes/threads could be performing inserts, you can't rely on the numbers being consecutive anymore even with transactions, but they would at least still be ordered relative to each other in each batch.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ok so my solution will be additional column in table to store order + rely on foreach order as it will insert from top to bottom

Comment: @JeroenMostert "`foreach` is guaranteed to use the order of the `IEnumerable` it operates on. "  but an `IEnuemrable` isn't guaranteed to be ordered. In fact, there are even cases where `IEnuerabme` is documented as unordered - such is the case of the `Keys` and `Values` properties of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` - enumerating these collection is only guaranteed they will always be in the same order. [Read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: @JeroenMostert but in my example (there is no threading or whatsoever) can i rely on that?